# How to convert process / cpu core based upon MIPS?

Tags: hardware, cpu

I want to know how can i find number of cpu cores/processor supported given i have the MIPS value?

For e.g I want to know the number of matching cores/processor to process speed of `18 trillion instructions / sec.`

Considering i don't have any no processor speed, can i use unit of measurement as in # of matches per second related to DB as processor speed?e.g 20 million matches per second

Comment: You question is hard to understand. For what I understand: If it is number of cores based on MIPS, you must have core speed.

Comment: Just take it as IPS. I'm interested in finding # of cores/processor required to support 18 trillion instructions / second.

Comment: Yes, but for that you must specify a core speed.

Comment: My calc e.g 1 core -> 2 instructions per cpu cycle -> speed 3Ghz -> at 6 billion instructions per second or 6000 MIPS

Comment: required_mips / core_speed = number_of_core: 18*10^12 / (6*10^9) = 3000 cores

Comment: But what i don't have core speed. I do have number of matches per second on DB. Would this do?

Comment: Depends on the database software, whether it's more or less optimized, the number of processor instruction per match can vary.

Comment: What if i say its teradata and its optimized. Optimized enough to serve entire country census data. I'm just looking for rough calculations. Is there a relationship between matches per second to processor speed?

Comment: I also have storage capacity ? with these two number helps u find any value of processor speed.

Comment: I don't find information on the net. Maybe you can try it (if you have access to it). Just measure on a normal server/computer, with the same architecture (x86/x64/ia64/etc...).

Comment: @Synxis first please reply this as answer so i can accept your response. You have been great help. I try to find net but its like industry or few guru secrets in what they can do with these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formulae is simple:

```
target_mips / mips_per_core = number_of_core
```

But here, you don't have `mips_per_core`; instead, you have number of database match per second. So, you have to see how much instructions are executed for a single match, for a specific database software *and* architecture.

**I advise you to measure the performances of a database on a computer whose architecture is the same than the ones used for the production database.**

Comment: do you have a number on AFIS matches per second to hardware specifications in terms of core supported.

Comment: Suppose, there is a database with 10 million fingerprints and a cluster of 100 nodes (PCs with 3GHz CPU). So with 300Ghz i can use the above formula to get number of cores?

Comment: First question: no, sorry - this information seems not to be available on the net. Maybe it's included in the software manual. Second question: 300 GHz / 3 GHz = 100, assuming the PCs have only one CPU core.

Comment: Excellent I'm using this as an estimate. http://www.fingerprint-it.com/sol_megamatcher.html.

Comment: I think this is more then what i required. You are a great help:)